# R Development: Use of `::` Operator for `base` Package

Tags: r, package, overloading, conventions, disambiguation

### TLDR

Does rigorous best practice recommend that a proactive R developer explicitly disambiguate all `base` functions — even the ubiquitously common functions like `c()` or `cat()` — within the `.R` files of their package, using the `package::function()` convention?

---

### Context

Though a novice developer, I need to create a (proprietary) package in R.  The text [*R Packages*](https://r-pkgs.org) (by the authoritative authors Hadley Wickham and Jenny Bryan) has proven extremely helpful (if occasionally deprecated).

I am keen on following best practices from the start, so as to save myself time and effort down the road.  As described [in the text](https://r-pkgs.org/namespace.html#namespace-motivation), the use of the `::` operator can prevent current *and*
future conflicts, by disambiguating functions whose names are overloaded.  To wit, the authors are careful to introduce each function with the `package::function()` convention, and they recommend its general use within the `.R` files of one's package.

However, their code examples often call functions that hail from the `base` package yet are unaccompanied by `base::`.  Many `base` functions, like the ubiquitous `c()` or `cat()`, are used by R programmers in their sleep and (I imagine) are *unlikely* to ever be overloaded by a presumptuous developer.  Nonetheless, it is confusing to see (for example) the juxtaposition of `base::with()` against (the `base` function) `print()`, all within [a few lines of text](https://r-pkgs.org/r.html#manage-state-with-withr).

> ...(These functions are inspired by how `base::with()` works.)
>
> ```
> f <- function(x, sig_digits) {
>   # imagine lots of code here
>   withr::with_options(
>     list(digits = sig_digits),
>     print(x)
>   )
>   # ... and a lot more code here
> }
> ```

I understand that the purpose of `base::with()` is to unambiguously introduce the `with()` function to the reader.  However, the absence of `base::` (within the code itself) seems to stick out like a sore thumb, when the package is explicitly named for any function called from any other package.  Given my inexperience, I don't feel comfortable assuming the authors' intent.

### Question

Are the names of `base` functions sufficiently unique that using this convention — of calling `base::function()` for every `function()` within the `base` package — would not be worth it?  That the risk of overloading the functions (at some point in the future) is far outweighed by the inconvenience (and sheer ugliness) of

```
my_vector <- base::c(1, 2, 3)
```

throughout one's `.R` files?  If not, is there an established convention that would balance unambiguity with elegance?

As always, I am grateful for any help, especially on this, my first post to Stack Overflow.

Comment: tldr: don't worry about it; if it becomes a problem, then fix it

Comment: @HongOoi Thanks for the advice! Would you expressly recommend *against* proactively using `base::function()` anyway (to avoid the hassle of going back and fixing it)?

Comment: I don't follow this convention. But if you do, where do you stop if you extend this to the base package? You will add significant overhead that hurts performance if you prepend every call to rather low-level functions. Also, operators (such as ::) are functions in R. Personally, I prefer rigorous namespace imports.